# no method named `downcast_ref` found for type parameter `T`

Tags: rust

Anyone have any idea why Im getting this error when `T` implements `Any`?

```
error[E0599]: no method named `downcast_ref` found for type parameter `T` in thecurrent scope
    --> src/main.rs:27:13

|
22 | impl<T: 'static + Any> UniTypeImpl for UniType<T> {
|      - method `downcast_ref` not found for this type parameter
...
27 |         val.downcast_ref::<T>()
|             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ method not found in `T`
```

--

```
use std::any::Any;

fn main() {
    let val = UniType::new(42);

    println!("{:?}", val.downcast());
}

trait UniTypeImpl {
    type StoredType;
    fn downcast(&self) -> Option<&Self::StoredType>;
}

struct UniType<T: 'static + Any>(T);

impl<T: 'static + Any> UniType<T> {
    fn new(value: T) -> Self {
        UniType(value)
    }
}

impl<T: 'static + Any> UniTypeImpl for UniType<T> {
    type StoredType = T;
    fn downcast(&self) -> Option<&Self::StoredType> {
        let UniType(val) = *self;

        val.downcast_ref::<T>()
    }
}
```

Comment: `downcast_ref` is available for [`dyn Any + 'static`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html#impl-dyn%20Any%20+%20%27static), not for any value implementing `Any`.

Comment: Plus, what's the point? `downcast_ref` is used to get a `&T` when you only have a `&dyn Any`, but in your case you already have a `T` so you can just return it: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=f052297bb21c68755caca0d92fab6433)

Comment: Side note: you don't need `'static + Any`, `Any` implies `'static` and `'static` implies `Any`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `downcast_ref` method is only available during dynamic dispatch. It is useless during static dispatch, so is implemented only for `dyn Any`.